# Iterator does not return the Element Object or does not Cast to its corresponding object?

Tags: java, jdom

Could someone please tell me why the Iterator in this code does not return with he Element Object?!?  Can't cast to Element Object! This is a JDOM implementation of SAX!

```
        org.xml.sax.InputSource inStream = new org.xml.sax.InputSource();

        inStream.setCharacterStream(new java.io.StringReader(temp));


        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();

        Document doc = builder.build(inStream);   
        ArrayList<String> queries = new ArrayList<String>();
        Element root = doc.getRootElement();

        Iterator elemIter = root.getDescendants();

        while (elemIter.hasNext()) {

            **Element tempElem = (Element)elemIter.next();** 
            String CDATA = tempElem.getChildText("ZQuery");
            queries.add(CDATA);
            elemIter.next();
        }
```

Comment: I suggest just walking the complete tree and write the types to your log. Then you'll see if you perhaps are looking into the wrong node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an [`ElementFilter`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/filter/ElementFilter.html) to [`getDescentdents(Filter filter)`](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Parent.html#getDescendants%28org.jdom.filter.Filter%29)

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <child1>
        <child11></child11>
        <child12></child12>
    </child1>
    <child2></child2>
</root>
```

Example

```
 SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
 Document document = builder.build(new File("src/com/foo/test.xml"));
 Element root = document.getRootElement();
 ElementFilter filter = new ElementFilter();
 Iterator i = root.getDescendants(filter);
 while (i.hasNext()) {
     Element element = (Element) i.next();
     System.out.println(element);
 }
```

Output

```
[Element: <child1/>]
[Element: <child11/>]
[Element: <child12/>]
[Element: <child2/>]
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooooooooooo much for your kind help!!!  You and whoever's helping out is a superstar!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this XML document:

```
<root>
    <child/>
</root>
```

The descendants of the root are:

- a text node containing the newline char + 4 spaces
- the child element
- a text node containing the newline char

Also, `getDescendants` walks through all the descendants, and not just the immediate children of the element. I'm pretty sure that it's not what you want.